# Exception occured: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, signal-processing, mfcc

I am trying to calculate mfcc and dtw of a wave using aquila DSP LIb. But when I execute the following code

```
 void main()
 {

     int frame_size =1024;

     Aquila::WaveFile waveIn0("a_converted.wav"); 
     Aquila::FramesCollection frameCollection0(waveIn0, frame_size);
     vector<vector<double>> dtwdt0;
     Aquila::Mfcc mfcc0(frame_size);

     for (int i=0; i<frameCollection0.count(); i++)
     {
         Aquila::Frame frame = frameCollection0.frame(i);
         vector<double> mfccValues = mfcc0.calculate(frame);
         dtwdt0.push_back(mfccValues);
     }

     Aquila::WaveFile waveIn1("a_converted.wav");
     Aquila::FramesCollection frameCollection1(waveIn1, frame_size);
     vector<vector<double>> dtwdt1;
     Aquila::Mfcc mfcc1(frame_size);

     for (int i = 0; i < frameCollection1.count(); i++)
     {
         Aquila::Frame frame = frameCollection1.frame(i);
         vector<double> mfccValues = mfcc1.calculate(frame);
         dtwdt1.push_back(mfccValues);
     }

     Aquila::Dtw dtw(Aquila::euclideanDistance,          Aquila::Dtw::PassType::Diagonals);
   double distance_1 = dtw.getDistance(dtwdt0, dtwdt1);
         cout << "Distance : " << distance_1 << endl;
  }
```

> **this exception occurred.  vector subscript out of range File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector Line:
>   1124**

What could be the issue?

Comment: what is dtw.getDistance? is `Aquila` namespace yours or from a third party library?

Comment: Why don't you look at the call stack in the debugger and see which exact lines are involved?

Comment: @UmNyobe     Aquila is a third party library for digital signal processing .... dtw.get distance is calculating the distance between two audio files..    and i am getting exception at                                                                             Aquila::Frame frame = frameCollection0.frame(i);